# remove last 10 characters of a file

Tags: c#, file

I want to remove the last 10 characters of a file. Say a string `"hello i am a c# learner"` is the data inside the file .

I just want that file to be `"hello i am a "`. The last 10 characters of the file that is the string `"c# learner"` should be eliminated inside the file.

**Solution:**

1. read the entire file into a string and remove those last 10 characters and write back the string (but this approach fails when the file size is too big say some 200 MB file and it is even  unnecessary way to read entire file when we need only last 10 characters. So I could not try this approach)
2. I thought to Open file in write mode and set the cursor position something like this `file.seek(-10,SeekOrigin.End)` and write empty bytes `file.writebye((byte)((char)' '));`

But it does not seem to write anything to the file.

Could anyone tell me the better way to approach it instead of reading entire file into a string.

**NOTE** I am using c# to do this

Comment: If your file is that small, reading the file into a string is a perfectly fine solution, especially with the way buffering works. It's simpler, and easier. If your file was really big, now that would be another story.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I just gave the sample piece. The file may be as big as 200 MB also. That depends on the user selection. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the file size (using FileInfo), open the file (using FileStream) and set its Length to the desired size.

Answer (score 8):

If the filepath is in the textbox:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.SetLength(fs.Length - 10);
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like that?

```
yourString = yourString.Remove(yourString.Length -10);
```